# Azure Files - How to obtain Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.dll?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I want to try the new Azure Files service (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/11/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx), and the PowerShell example starts with this line

```
import-module .\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.dll
```

This fails for me, even though I have just installed the most recent version of Azure PowerShell.

> import-module : The specified module '.\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.dll' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in
>   any module directory.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + import-module .\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.dll
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (.\Microsoft.Win...torage.File.dll:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Where can I obtain this file? I searched google, and the only place this one is mentioned is the aforementioned tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blog post is now updated with details on how to install the cmdlets: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/11/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx#faq7

Comment: Downloading the latest standalone msi and then running repair worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Please download the zip file containing this and other files from here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398183

You may need to unblock the cmdlet using:

```
unblock-file .\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.dll
```

From what I have been told, Azure Storage team missed out this link in the blog post which they will be updating soon.